# Deploying Phonegap 2.x App Development on another Mac

Tags: xcode, html, cordova

I used to develop PhoneGap Apps by using 1.x PhoneGap library or Cordova library.  After that, I use Cordova 2.x library, and I got confused.

I push my sources to Github and let my friends fork it.  We don't know how to deploy the development environment on another Macbook even if that Macbook has the Cordova 2.x library.

First, we found that the project did not have the Cordova lib. So, we Added Cordova 2.x library into the project.But Xcode gave us an error.

If I built Cordova Lib Xcode said :

> File
>   /Users/[MYUSERNAME]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[MYAPPNAME]-gfayprtpflnyaqcwfmepqwlyjglq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
>   depends on itself.  This target might include its own product. build
>   cordova 2.x Lib

If I build `MYAPPNAME` Xcode said :

> Unknow type name "CDVViewController"

Answer (score 1):

in phonegap folder you find something called update script run it and give it your project adress it should do the job(update references and more) you could find more in phonegap website

Comment: I had tried it.But the terminal shows these: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/update_cordova_subproject", line 71, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "bin/update_cordova_subproject", line 66, in main
    raise Exception('Sub-project entry not found in project file.')
Exception: Sub-project entry not found in project file.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve my problem by reading this article.

And follow the steps like the author's saying ...

Here is the link : http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/10/installing-cordovaphonegap-2-1-for-ios/